# Httpd option APACHE_MODULES loads modules that LoadModule doesn't load

Tags: apache-2.4

While trying to solve [Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType' but mod_filter already loaded](https://serverfault.com/q/915801/242122) I've noticed that if I add modules to the `APACHE_MODULES` directive in `/etc/sysconfig/apache2` (this is a SUSE Linux Enterprise box), that error disappears and in fact the server successfully starts.

It looks like `LoadModule` is not loading some modules, but not giving any error.

Is it a matter of module loading order or does `APACHE_MODULES` list all the modules that are allowed to be loaded?

Where can I find documentation for `APACHE_MODULES` and the other options like `APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS`?